# Synapse Home server(Matrix) not running

Tags: macos, server, matrix-synapse

I have installed synapse using the following commands:

link: https://github.com/matrix-org/synapse

Installing prerequisites on Mac OS X:

```
xcode-select --install
sudo easy_install pip
sudo pip install virtualenv
brew install pkg-config libffi
```

To install the synapse homeserver run:

```
virtualenv -p python2.7 ~/.synapse
source ~/.synapse/bin/activate
pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install https://github.com/matrix-org/synapse/tarball/master
```

Generate a configuration file

```
cd ~/.synapse
python -m synapse.app.homeserver \
    --server-name my.domain.name \
    --config-path homeserver.yaml \
    --generate-config \
    --report-stats=yes
```

To get started, it is easiest to use the command line to register new users:

```
$ source ~/.synapse/bin/activate
$ synctl start # if not already running
$ register_new_matrix_user -c homeserver.yaml https://localhost:8448
New user localpart: user123
Password:
Confirm password:
```

Server started successfully, but user registration failed and

i opened "https://localhost:8448" in the browser and i got the following:

[image]

Can anybody help to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Your homeserver is probably not starting correctly. Try to get the *JSON response about supported versions* by executing following in you shell:

```
curl https://localhost:8448/_matrix/client/versions -k
```

This should result in a JSON response listing protocol versions:

```
{
    "versions": [
        "r0.0.1",
        "r0.1.0",
        "r0.2.0"
    ]
}
```

If that's not working - to find out the real issue you can try:

1. Check if it's running at all with `sudo service matrix-synapse status`
2. Check the log file at `/var/log/matrix-synapse/homeserver.log`

---

I will update the answer, in case you can provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

The web client should be accessible at the following URL:

https://localhost:8448/_matrix/client/

However the documentation states:

> (The homeserver runs a web client by default at
>   https://localhost:8448/, though as of the time of writing it is
>   somewhat outdated and not really recommended -
>   https://github.com/matrix-org/synapse/issues/1527).

You should use a client such as the one at https://riot.im/app/

Comment: FYI - The client is not activated anymore.